# Maximum number of qubits supported by the Qasm simulator

Tags: qiskit, programming, resource-request

By using the Qiskit qasm-simulator, I want to simulate a quantum circuit of 40 qubits. However, the number of qubits 40 is greater than maximum number (24) for qasm-simulator. Is there any possibility to increase this number?

Comment: Hey, could you tell me how you found this 24 limit? When searching I have a 30 limits but no 24 anywhere

Comment: The limit is set by the available local RAM.  As such, there is variation in the limits.

Answer (score 5):

Actually, the maximum number of qubits in the local `qasm_simulator` is 30, and 32 for the `ibmq_qasm_simulator`. You can see this 30-limit by running `Aer.get_backend('qasm_simulator').configuration().to_dict()` and you can see the configuration for the simulator, including the max number of qubits.

However, I believe it is possible to play with the matrix product state option to get a little bit more, I am not sure, I invite you to check [this tuto](https://qiskit.org/documentation/tutorials/simulators/7_matrix_product_state_method.html?highlight=matrix%20product%20state) from Qiskit, they might go through it :)

EDIT : Actually the 24-limit comes from BasicAer, I invite you to use the simulators from Aer, or the ibmq_qasm_simulator that have better limits. You can also play with the backend options, see in [this documentation from Qiskit](https://qiskit.org/documentation/stubs/qiskit.providers.aer.QasmSimulator.html?highlight=backend_option) that explains pretty much everything there is to know!

Hope this helps :)

Comment: More specifically, the following command will give you the max number of qubits:
`Aer.get_backend('qasm_simulator').configuration().n_qubits`

Answer (score 0):

If you use `ibmq_qasm_simulator` then the maximum number of qubit supported is 32. And you can't increase this number. Here is [Qiskit documentation](https://quantum-computing.ibm.com/docs/manage/backends/simulators/) on this simulator.

Remember that simulating quantum system is very resource extensive, and being able to simulating a system with 32 qubits is pretty impressive.

Comment: On my PC, Qiskit runs under the Windows XP operating system. When I submit the circuit code to the qasm simulator I got the following message back: qiskit.providers.basicaer.exceptions.BasicAerError: 'Number of qubits 40 is greater than maximum (24) for "qasm_simulator'.

Comment: note that there is a difference between `qasm_simulator` and `ibmq_qasm_simulator`. The latter run on IBM's cluster which is (I guess) pretty powerful.